# Update multiple rows with different values but with one where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is a table which includes data of store and are identified by order_id.

| order_id | erp_id | Serial_No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | ML456G | null |
| 1234567 | ML456G | null |
| 1234567 | ML456G | null |

In the table you can see order_id and erp_id both are same. Now I have a file which includes set of order_id's and erp_id's and data for serial_no column is null at the moments but need to be filled as below table.

| order_id | erp_id | Serial_No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | ML456G | 12345678952 |
| 1234567 | ML456G | 75685212542 |
| 1234567 | ML456G | 56821236254 |

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: The serial numbers are in a file? Not in a database table? Then the first job is probably to import them. Or you write a programm that loops through the file and updates single table rows.

Comment: Yes serials are in excel file and can be imported in external table for ease.

Comment: I think the easiest approach may be a loop in a programming language. Either from outside the DB (maybe in Excel VBA?) or inside with PL/SQL.

Comment: Along with data you currently have, provide sample of the file contents (which will probably be stored into a table). It is difficult to guess which serial_no should be used for which order_id + erp_id combination.

Comment: 2nd table actually represents the data in excel file and database table.. since the order_id and erp_id is same, we are allowed to assign serials with any combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by exporting a data in excel and generating a helper column and then vlookup to update the desired column.
Thanks All :)